# Can any sequence of RVs converge almost surely to a non-constant RV?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We know for almost sure convergence, $X_n \rightarrow X \text{ a.s. as } n\rightarrow \infty$ if
$$
P\{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n = \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\} = 1.
$$

Then does this mean the limiting random variable $X$ must be a constant (random variable)?

Comment: What if all the $X_n$ are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Try $X_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n2^{-k}Y_k$, where $(Y_k)$ is i.i.d. with $P(Y_k=0)=P(Y_k=1)=\frac12$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I really appreciate your help. The example gives me a deeper and clearer understanding of almost sure convergence, which concerns about the point-wise (in the sample space) limit of RVs. By the way, I wonder how you came up with this example?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what convergence means for random variables, you have to realize that you don't sample a *single* random variable multiple times to construct the sequences, but rather take a joint sample of *countably* many random variables. For that, *all* the random variables have to refer to the same probability space. Thus, each element of the probability space maps to a whole sequence of real numbers - one for each random variable.

Now, some of these sequences might converge, and some might not. You can then look at the set of elements of your probability space which map to *convering* sequences. If the measure (i.e. probability) of that set is 1, the random variables converge almost surely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thorough explanation! It really helps!